# Sharepoint library custom link

Tags: content-type

In my document library, I want to add link like : "\server1\doc.txt" but it's impossible, it require "http" : http://puu.sh/j9GWk/f18c98ab5f.png

I try to create new content type and hide "URL" but I have one form with URL required
Do you have an idea to just put a link in a library document without "http" required?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a single line of text column and then you can add "\server1\doc.txt" to it. The hyperlink column expects an actual hyperlink.

Comment: No because when I click on "Add", I have a form with URL required "http", and AFTER I have a second form with my custom content type

Comment: I'm saying that you don't use a hyperlink column, use a Single Line of Text field where you can put the UNC path or the partial path.